# Обновление состояния базы данных в django-консоли

Tags: python, django, pycharm, django-orm

Есть тестовый сервер, есть тестовая база данных. В django shell PyCharm-a в целях тестирования создаются инстансы и моделируются некие действия между ними, но при параллельном создании во фронтенде объекта записи в базе данных, которая представляет одну из используемых при тестировании django-моделей (SomeModel, например), не могу получить доступ к этому объекту с помощью конструкции

```
sm = SomeModel.objects.get(id=10)
```

Выводится исключение:

> DoesNotExist: SomeModel matching query does not exist.

После перезагрузки джанго-консоли все в порядке - объект находится.

Так вот, каким образом можно обновить состояние мира в консоли без ее перезагрузки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день.
Поскольку по умолчанию django shell использует ipython, то это можно сделать двумя способами:
1:

```
from app import models
sm = models.SomeModel.objects.get(id=10)
#теперь нужно перезагрузить модуль
reload(models)
```

2:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```